# Solution of differential equation with two variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a differential equation with variables x(t) and y(t), and a following differential equation:

$$xy \frac{d}{dt}\Big{(}\frac{x}{y}\Big{)} = c_{1} (y-x)-c_{2} \quad c_{1}~ \text{and}~c_{2}~\text{are}~\text{constants}$$

This equation comes from a coupled differential equation system, which describes the derivatives of x(t) and y(t).

Maybe a new variable which contains x(t) and y(t) can help to find the solution of this equation instead of solving the original equation system.

(The original system is 
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \gamma xy-\alpha xy-\gamma x^{2}-\gamma\beta x\qquad(1)\\ 
\frac{dy}{dx} = \gamma xy-\alpha xy-\gamma y^{2}\qquad (2)$$

I tried to simplifying the system with these steps:
$$ \frac{\dot{x}}{x} = \gamma y-\alpha y-\gamma x-\gamma\beta \qquad(1) \\ 
\frac{\dot{y}}{y} = \gamma x-\alpha x-\gamma y \qquad(2)\\
(1)-(2) \rightarrow \frac{\dot{x}}{x}-\frac{\dot{y}}{y} = (2\gamma-\alpha)(y-x)-\gamma\beta\\
\frac{\dot{x}y-\dot{y}x}{xy} = (2\gamma-\alpha)(y-x)-\gamma\beta\\
\frac{y}{x}\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big) = (2\gamma-\alpha)(y-x)-\gamma\beta \\
\frac{y}{x}\frac{d}{dt}\Big{(}\frac{x}{y}\Big{)} = c_{1} (y-x)-c_{2} \qquad \text{where}~c_{1} =2\gamma-\alpha\qquad~c_{2} = \gamma\beta $$

Comment: How can you solve one equation with two functions?

Comment: @Mattos It will be enough to know z(t) = x(t)+y(t) or something like that.

Comment: But how do you then determine $x$ and $y$ explicitly?

Comment: @Mattos I posted the original differential equation system, but I don't need the solution x(t) and y(t) explicitly, I need only a solution for a new variable which contains x(t) and y(t), for example the ratio or the sum of them.